# Perl: How to use command line special characters (newline, tab) in $LIST_SEPARATOR ($")

Tags: perl, special-characters, command-line-arguments

I would like to use the value of a variable (fixed by a command line option for instance) as a list separator, enabling that value to be a special character (newline, tabulation, etc.).

Unfortunately the naïve approach does not work due to the fact that the two following print statement behave differentely :

```
my @tab = ("a","b","c");

# block 1 gives expected result:
# a
# b
# c
{
  local $" = "\n";                    #" let us please the color syntax engine
  print "@tab";
}

# block 2 gives unwanted result:
# a\nb\nc
{
  use Getopt::Long;
  my $s;
  GetOptions('separator=s' => \$s);
  local $" = "$s";                    #" let us please the color syntax engine
  print "@tab";
}
```

Any idea I can correct the block 2 so that I get the wanted result (the one produced by block 1) ?

Answer (score 3):

It actually does work the same if you assign the same string. Perl's

```
"\n"
```

creates a one character string consisting of a newline. With my shell (bash), you'd use

```
'
'
```

to do the same.

```
$ perl a.pl --separator='
'
a
b
ca
b
c
```

You didn't do this. You passed a string consisting of the two characters `\` and `n` to Perl instead.

If you your program to convert two chars `\n` into a newline, you'll need to tell it to do so.

```
my @tab = qw( a b c );

sub handle_escapes {
  my ($s) = @_;
  $s =~ s/\\([\\a-z])/
    $1 eq '\\' ? '\\' :
    $1 eq 'n' ? "\n" :
    do { warn("Unrecognised escape \\$1"); "\\$1" }
  /seg;
  return $s;
}

{
  my $s = '\n';                     #" let us please the color syntax engine
  local $" = handle_escapes($s);
  print "@tab";
}

{
  use Getopt::Long;
  my $s;
  GetOptions('separator=s' => \$s);
  local $" = handle_escapes($s);    #" let us please the color syntax engine
  print "@tab";
}
```

```
$ perl a.pl --separator='\n'
a
b
ca
b
c
```